# How do you handle "that that"? The double "that" problem

Tags: adjectives, pronouns, sentence-patterns, repetition, doubled-words

Have you ever had a case where you felt compelled to include strange things like a double *that* in a sentence? If so, then what did you do to resolve this?

For me, I never knew whether it was acceptable grammar. However, what I did learn was that it was a *logic distractor*, could lead to confusion, and therefore should be reworded to avoid this.

Comment: Am I the only one thinking about buffaloes?

Comment: Had had had the same issue.

Comment: Don't forget that that "that" that appears before the other "that" does a different job.

Comment: The two 'that's get pronounced differently here, at least when I say them, this isn't as confusing when it's spoken as when it's written.

Comment: whenever somebody needs an example of correct usage of that that just quote:  "We have come to dedicate a portion of that field, as a final resting place for those who here gave their lives that that nation might live. It is altogether fitting and proper that we should do this." A. Lincoln

Comment: For anyone else confused by the buffalo reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo

Comment: James while John had had had had had had had had had had had a better effect on the teacher

Comment: Wow am I the only one completely confused by every comment on here that has "that" more than 3 times in a sentence?

Comment: That "that that" repetition is an infelicity that that author might have avoided with a bit of rewording so that that "that that" juxtaposition never found its way into print.

Comment: Avoiding these kinds of constructions in the name of clarity is a self-fulfilling prophecy. The less one encounters them, the more one will stumble upon them.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

There are three very different uses of *that*:

- Subordinating *that*: “I know *that* this is the answer.”
- Demonstrative pronoun *that*: “*That* is not the answer.”
- Adjectival *that*: “*That* answer is not it.”

Double *that* occurs because the first *that* is the subordinating *that*, and the second *that* is a demonstrative pronoun or adjectival *that*. That is, if you subordinate a clause that begins with pronominal or adjectival *that* with *that*, you get *that that*, as in “you know that that *that that* from the previous sentence was different from the one in this sentence.”

Comment: From your explanation, I now realize it is acceptable grammar. However, for readability, it is a distraction. Therefore, I think a sentence should be reworked to avoid it.

Comment: Too bad your handle is not "nothat".

Comment: My dad Pat and brother Matt thought that that _that that_ that nohat had everybody have down pat was neat.

Comment: Nowadays, often classified as complementiser, (distal) demonstrative pronoun and distal demonstrative determiner.

Comment: @Volomike *"However, for readability, it is a distraction"* It really depends on the context. I try to confine its usage to dialogue, since it's by no means uncommon in day-to-day conversation.

Comment: @nohat, But isn't the first "that" (the subordinating one) optional?

Comment: Does someone have an example sentence involving a "triple" that?

Comment: I know that that "that that" was used correctly. :-D

Answer (score 25):

Of course it is acceptable *grammar*. The rules of English grammar are the very reason why such "strange things" happen in the first place.

Now, whether or not you actually end up using a double "that" or rewording it, is a different question. But it is a question of *style*. Read: personal preference.

Personally, more often than not, I don't find a double "that" to be distracting or leading to confusion at all. Quite the contrary: it is a) perfectly self-explanatory and b) it certainly leads to *less* confusion than leaving one of those "that"s out.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think that that is a problem.

Having said that, it would still make sense if one of the "that"s in the previous sentence were omitted.

EDIT: In response to Reg's comment:

If a "that" is omitted, it's the first one that is removed. Replacing the second "that" with "it" may clarify things:

> I don't think that **it** is a problem.
>
> I don't think **it** is a problem.

Hence saying "I don't think that is a problem" is fine - as long as you're familiar with this particular usage of the word "that". If not, then it could obviously cause confusion.

Comment: Yeah, but that is just one kind of "that that". Here's another one: "I don't think that that problem is serious." Everyone is happily parsing that as "[I don't think that] [that problem is serious]", and everything is hunky-dory. Now we try our nifty trick of dropping one of the "that"s — "I don't think that problem is serious" —, and we immediately get a certain amount of people who parse the sentence as "[I don't think that] [problem is serious]" on their first try, and get terribly confused, and have to go back and try a different parsing. (Is that a garden-path sentence yet?)

Comment: Interesting example and thought process here, Reg.

Answer (score 5):

This is correct. The two words are performing different functions. The first *that* is used to introduce a clause. The second *that* is used to refer to a specific thing.

Answer (score 4):

I would argue that it might very well be correct, but if it makes you uncomfortable, it may also distract your readers. You've likely seen the common example:

> The human brain often skips any extra
>   words that appear in the the sentence
>   they're reading

The same behaviour might happen with the extra "that" appearing in your sentence. So while it might be correct in theory, perhaps you could reword your sentence such that it becomes more readable for your audience.

Comment: +1.  Just because something’s grammatically correct doesn’t mean it’s *good*.

Comment: If you're saying that that that will be ignored, why not just leave it in? (Tried to work in a fourth "that"; failed.)

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly fine to write "that that" or to simply write "that": your choice, your style, your need at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is about how do **I** handle the problem personally, I always try to minimize my usage of the word "that" in order to avoid these instances altogether.

"That bike that is blue" becomes "**the** bike **which** is blue" or simply, "the blue bike."  Therefore: "That that is blue" becomes "that which is blue" or even "what is blue" in some contexts.

"I know that it is true" becomes "I know it is true."  I simply omit the word "that" and it still works.

"That that is true" becomes "That which is true" or simply, "The truth."

I do this not because it is grammatically incorrect, but because it is more aesthetically pleasing.  The overuse of the word "that" is a hallmark of lazy speech.  Indeed, if avoiding these instances causes you to think outside the box, your speech and writing will become more fresh and creative as a result.

To clarify, I don't go out of my way to avoid the word "that."  I simply reduce my daily usage of it in order to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I use 'that that' quite often because it gives you an explicit reference to the exact subject referred to previously. Simply replacing it with 'this' sometimes will not do as I sometimes wish to refer to 'that' specifically.