# "I don't think that that can be done"

Tags: adjectives, pronouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you handle “that that”? The double “that” problem](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3418/how-do-you-handle-that-that-the-double-that-problem)

Is there something wrong with this sentence?

> "I don't think that that can be done."

It sounds odd to me. Would it be better if I'd use just one "that" instead of two:

> "I don't think that can be done."

Comment: Related: [Use of "that" in a sentence](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/use-of-that-in-a-sentence/1102#1102).

Comment: Maybe  _"I don't think it can be done"_ could be used instead.  Any time you have the same two words next to each other you start to confuse people.  (despite the fact that that's syntactically correct)

Comment: @advs89: Sometimes it confuses people, but not always. Sometimes, having two words in a row can show when you are really really emphatic about something.

Comment: @Kosmonaut:  very very true

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both are correct, but the second is preferred.

In option 1, the first *that* serves as a conjunction introducing the subordinate clause "that can be done," which is the object of the verb *think*. The second *that* is simply a pronoun substituting for the subject of the subordinate clause.

Option 2 is better because (1) it avoids the awkwardness of the double *that* and (2) the sentence is still perfectly intelligible without the conjunctive *that*.

That is quite a flexible word. :)

Comment: "the second is preferred" by who?

Comment: Possibly by those who use phrases like 'the second is preferred' :D

Comment: I don't think that _that_ can be a [gerund](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_gb0333360#m_en_gb0333360). Can it? It's something I've never heard of. Can you link this to a source?

Comment: @Tragicomic: I didn't say *that* was a gerund.

Comment: @Kelly At first I read it as "simply [a pronoun substituting for a noun] or [in this case maybe a gerund]". +1 anyway, good answer.

Comment: Note that there are plenty of other things that *that* might stand for (another pronoun like *it*, an *-ing* clause like *pleading the Fifth in response to a subpoena*, a *wh* clause like *what he wants to do*) so you might as well just say "simply a pronoun substituting for the subject of the clause", which covers them all.

Comment: @Jason: Edited for clarity per your comments. Thanks for the vote!

Answer (score 2):

In that sentence, *that* can be omitted, similarly to what is done in the following sentences.

> He will understand I was not joking.
>   Several people read the question you wrote.
>   I am sure you will be able to resolve the issue.

I would write the sentence avoiding to write *that* twice, but that doesn't mean it is wrong to write "that that."

Answer (score 0):

Although *both* are grammatically correct, the second one is quite natural. I said *natural* because, native speakers spontaneously use the second form. In linguistics, this phenomenon is called as the *competence* - native speakers intuitively choose the second sentence because, they know (naturally) that the first sentence would sound awkward.

Anyone using a sentence similar to the first one is undoubtedly a *non-native* speaker! This condition will be vanished once the non-native speakers start socializing with native speakers.