# Better use of "that that" — or not

Tags: adjectives, conjunctions, sentence-patterns, repetition, doubled-words

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you handle “that that”? The double “that” problem](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3418/how-do-you-handle-that-that-the-double-that-problem)

I sometimes seem to write myself into using 2 thats in succession, as in:

"Now that that issue has been resolved, we can move forward."

I am pretty sure that this is correct but is it bad form and should it be avoided?

Comment: 9 times out of 10 you can just write / say a single *that*, and that's that.

Answer (score 3):

It's not ungrammatical, but if it bothers you you could try:

> Now that this issue has been resolved ...
>
> Now that the issue has been resolved ...
>
> Since the issue has been resolved ...
>
> Given that the issue has been resolved ...
>
> The issue has been resolved, so ...

And any number of alternate constructions.