# Omitting "that" when connecting clauses

Tags: grammar

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Use of “that” in a sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/use-of-that-in-a-sentence)
>   [How do you handle “that that”? The double “that” problem](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3418/how-do-you-handle-that-that-the-double-that-problem)

What exactly is the recommendation, when I'm writing, to do with the word "that"?

Often, while speaking, someone might say:

> I think it's going to rain.

Whereas, technically, it should be:

> I think **that** it's going to rain.

However, things can get complicated when using the word "that" to refer to an object such as "this or that":

> I guess that would be the right thing to do.

versus:

> I guess **that** that would be the right thing to do.

Is the latter even grammatically correct?

What should I do in these cases?  Should I add the word "that" in all cases, or only cases where it might be ambiguous otherwise?  Should I always omit it?  Should I repeat the word "that" twice when appropriate, or should I always list it once in these cases?