# Two consecutive "that", "that that"

Tags: meaning, repetition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you handle “that that”? The double “that” problem](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3418/how-do-you-handle-that-that-the-double-that-problem)

I've encountered this sentence in a technical book:

> A browsing context has a session history, which lists the Document objects that that browsing context has presented.

What is the grammaticall role of each "that" here? Can we consider using two consecutive "that" as a poor writing style from the point of user understanding?

Answer (score 0):

The first "that" means the same as the word "which" in this context, and so can easily be replaced with it as such:

> A browsing context has a session history, which lists the Document objects which that browsing context has presented.

The second "that" refers to the "browsing context".

I use "that" twice consecutively on occasion, but I will often try to rephrase the sentence to do away with that potentially awkward construct. For example, I can rewrite your given sentence as:

> A browsing context has a session history, which lists the Document objects presented by that browsing context.