# "That that" vs. "that"

Tags: redundancy, repetition

Is "that that" or "that, that" redundant in sentences such as this:

> The reason we are late is that that we had an accident.

or

> The reason we are late is that, that we had an accident.

Is it ok if I just say:

> The reason we are late is that we had an accident.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3418/how-do-you-handle-that-that-the-double-that-problem

Comment: The first two don't even make sense. The third is the only grammatically correct one.

Comment: When I saw the title I was not expecting that that would be your question.  Your examples are indeed redundant and incorrect.

Comment: I really can’t see how that that that that you put after that other that makes that that make any sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, you only want one "that."

> The reason we are late is that we had an accident.

*The reason* for this *is that* the construction is **"the reason ... is that..."**.

Example of a double "that" --

> "I think that that car is the fastest." 
>   (no comma)

Or, to use your original sentence, something like: --

> The reason we are late is that that man's hesitation slowed us down.

(or something like that -- still no comma)