# Is repeating the word "that" ok, if it is technically, grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, writing-style, repetition, vernacular

E.g.:

> "... with all the sustainability considerations that that entails."

If I'm correct, the above example is *relative pronoun* followed by *pronoun* - it just happens to be the same word for both grammatically legitimate, albeit adjacent words.

Or, even an example with three *that's* in a row:

> "It wasn't that that that was referring to."

The above sentence may even sound natural in common speech if delivered fluently and in a context in which it was fully understood.

So if one accepts grammatical correctness and one is being clear in it being known what the examples of *that* are adjuncts for, are repeated *that's* acceptable after all?

Comment: For your mind-numbing pleasure, I offer that ultimate that that of thats: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/That_that_is_is_that_that_is_not_is_not_is_that_it_it_is

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1095  and of http://english.stackexchange.com/q/3418, both incredibly ancient questions. Please use the search function to avoid asking duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the duplicates; but in my defence, if you start a new question with the exact title of mine (https://i.imgur.com/qG1e7YL.png), the ones above simply don't show up in the provided "Questions that may already have your answer" list; and yet it is a duplicate as you have both usefully pointed out. Is there a technique I can employ to better find questions that have already asked what I am asking despite wording it in an entirely different way?

Comment: Try [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22that%22++is%3Aquestion) search to start :).

Comment: @HowardPautz - Re: That "that" that that guy was discussing in that wiki article.  Boy was that "that" weird!