# When can I omit a redundant 'that'?

Tags: grammar, that

Can I omit a 'that' from the sentence

> I am confident that that can make me $50

so that it becomes

> I am confident that can make me $50
> Please and thank you.

Comment: You can *always* omit anything that's redundant. That's what "redundant" *means*. Or are you really wondering how to determine what's redundant and what isn't? Because the two *thats* in this case are not redundant at all. They are two completely different words that serve two completely unrelated functions. In the sentence *Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo*, none of the buffalos are redundant.

Comment: You may want to read these two Q&A threads from the site: [The double 'that' problem](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3418/how-do-you-handle-that-that-the-double-that-problem) (ELU) and [Omission of "that"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56579/omission-of-that-in-this-text) (ELL).